# Copy lxd containers between hosts

Tags: ubuntu, lxc, containers

I've installed lxd on two ubuntu hosts that can only communicate via an intermediate server (on which I don't have su privileges).  I've created a container on my localhost and now wish to load the container on the remote server.

I consulted the [basic.sh](https://github.com/lxc/lxd/blob/master/test/suites/basic.sh) test script in the lxc/lxd repo to confirm that I'm using the correct approach (I discovered along the way that I was misunderstanding images vs containers).

I've created a container *test* on my localhost, installed all the necessary goodies within it, stopped it, published it, and executed the following commands:

```
lxc image export test
```

This gives me a tarball *42cf01c53cb9e...83e3c48.tar.gz* (shortened here), as described in the documentation (I'm running lxc and lxd versions 2.0.0.beta3). Attempting to import that image on the same host via

```
lxc image import 42cf01c53cb9e...83e3c48.tar.gz --alias testimage
```

yields the error:

```
exit status 2 (tar: metadata.yaml: Not found in archive)
```

The [basic.sh](https://github.com/lxc/lxd/blob/master/test/suites/basic.sh) script leads me to believe that I was following the correct route though (except for the tar.gz vs tar.xz descrepancY). I'm able to export standard images and obtain an .xz file (when I obtain them using lxd-images). For example,

```
lxd-images import ubuntu --alias ubuntu
lxc image export ubuntu
```

produces a *meta-ubuntu...tar.xz* and *ubuntu...tar.xz* file, which can be imported (on a different server) with

```
lxc image import meta...tar.xz rootfs ubuntu...tar.xz --alias imported_ubuntu
```

How do I copy containers between hosts?

Thanks!

Edit: I've investigated further and have published my test container, which creates an image of it. Then I get the .gz file though (without the meta-data) when I export it. If I hijack metadata from the original image, then I can't get the container started although import no longer crashes on me --- I obviously don't know what I'm doing. Pulling the image over to a second host using lxd's *remote:* approach (after adding the host using the lxd config) does not result in it appearing in *lxc images list*.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The later release (non-beta) of lxd (v2.0) seems to have resolved my issue. The steps, which may be found in the excellent documentation [here](https://insights.ubuntu.com/2016/04/01/lxd-2-0-image-management-512/), are:

1. Publish an image (without stopping the container) on host A;

   ```
   $ lxc publish --force container_name --alias image_name
   Container published with fingerprint: d2fd708361...a125d0d5885
   ```
2. Export the image to a file;

   ```
   $ lxc image export image_name 
   Output is in dd2fd708361...a125d0d5885.tar.gz
   ```
3. Copy the file to host B, and import;

   ```
   $ lxc image import dd2fd708361...a125d0d5885.tar.gz --alias image_name
   Transferring image: 100%
   ```
4. Launch the container (from the image) on host B;

   ```
   $ lxc launch image_name container_name
   Creating container_name
   Starting container_name
   ```

In some instances the publish command may lead to a split xz tar-ball --- but both formats are [supported](https://github.com/lxc/lxd/issues/1973). Simply import the meta-data and rootfs components with

```
    lxc image import <metadata tarball> <rootfs tarball> --alias image_name
```

Comment: The `--force` option actually _does_ stop the container. It just causes it to restart after the process is done, as noted by @Levi's answer below.

Comment: Also, you could add a `remote` and then use the `lxc image copy ...` command to move the images around that way, which would be a lot easier than exporting, etc. For example: `lxc image copy --alias=<your-alias> --auto-update <your-remote>:<image-to-move> local:` will download the image to the system you ran the command from (i.e. your backup location, etc)

Answer (score 4):

0_0 posted a good answer but I'm not allowed to comment just yet so I will just post his answer modified.

First off `lxc publish --force container_name --alias image_name` will stop the container and restart it but the OP did not want the container to be stopped.

You should make a snapshot first with `lxc snapshot container_name snapshot_name`

Then you can publish the image with `lxc publish container_name/snapshot_name --alias image_name`

Now just follow the rest of his instructions.

Comment: Thanks! I see `-f, --force Stop the container if currently running` in the help for `lxc publish`; don't know what I was thinking.

Answer (score 0):

If you have socat or netcat or gcc / python / perl / anything that can listen on tcp, then you could also listen on the intermediate server and forward the connection to the other host